# Exchange 2010 - - - Attachment Retention Solution

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Currently I am working with getting rid of voicemail to email files to save space in our archiving solution. Currently I have a search-mailbox script written to take care of deleting the voicemail e-mails. Is there any other solution out there that would be more effective in controlling the deletion of specific attachments from users mailboxes? The script works but it seems crude and very ancient to me after I finished writing it. I also looked at Transport Rules and Retention Tags but neither seem to give me much granular control over just attachments or just a specific attachment name. Is there an Industry Standard on handling a situation similar to mine or am I headed in the right direction with just PowerShell?

Comment: This might be a better fit for ServerFault. Right now this is too broad for SO.

Comment: Can we move the post there then? If not, ill take it over there with a copy and paste ;)